# pycaffe windows - cannot open python27.lib

Tags: python, caffe, pycaffe

I am trying to compile pycaffe in Windows 7 using Anaconda 3 and Visual studio 2013. I have set the anaconda path and lib path correctly. When I try to build I am getting the following error:

"Error  1   error LNK1104: cannot open file 'python27.lib'  D:\caffe-master\windows\caffe\LINK  caffe"

I am using Python 3.6 but not sure why the build is looking for 2.7 lib. How do I make build pick the correct python lib?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same error while building matcaffe interface with python 3.5, so I downgraded Anaconda and Python to 2.7 version and it successed.